# Sumar los resultados de un select añadiendo una nueva fila

Tags: mysql

Supongo que será sencillisimo pero por mas que busco no encuentro como realizarlo.
Tengo un par de tablas, de las cuales he obtenido el numero total de productos para cada marca pero me gustaría poder añadir una ultima fila que sume esos resultados.
Como lo tengo ahora es asi:

```
SELECT brands.BrandName,
SUM(Quantity)AS 'Units'
FROM products 
INNER JOIN brands ON products.BrandID = brands.BrandID
GROUP BY products.BrandID
```

Y la tabla resultante es:

```
BrandName   Units   
Samsung     35
Apple       11
Huawei      64
```

Me gustaria que apareciera una que ponga Total y el resultado de la suma de todas las unidades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agregar un registro más con el `Total` (*la suma de todas las unidades*)  podrías hacer un `UNION`, así por ejemplo:

```
SELECT brands.BrandName,
    SUM(Quantity)AS 'Units'
FROM products 
    INNER JOIN brands 
        ON products.BrandID = brands.BrandID
GROUP BY products.BrandID
UNION (SELECT 'Total',
        SUM(Quantity)
   FROM products
   INNER JOIN brands 
        ON products.BrandID = brands.BrandID)
```

**PD:** El `INNER JOIN` en la segunda consulta podría omitirse si todos los `products` tienen un `BrandID` que corresponde a un registro existente en la tabla `brands`.

Comment: Fantastico muchisimas gracias, exactamente como lo necesitaba. Como si que lo tienen efectivamente funciona tambien perfectamente sin el INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Podria probar de hacer una columna con un subquery:

```
SELECT brands.BrandName,
       SUM(Quantity) AS 'Units', 
       (SELECT 
           SUM(Quantity)
        FROM products
        INNER JOIN brands
              ON products.BrandID =brands.BrandID) AS 'TotalUnits'
FROM products
INNER JOIN brands 
     ON products.BrandID = brands.BrandID
GROUP BY products.BrandID
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo agrega `WITH ROLLUP;`, así:

> GROUP BY products.BrandID WITH ROLLUP;